# How to extract generated attribute from a previously defined resource?

Tags: terraform, resources

This is not related to aws but to a technique of extracting data from a resource collection; therefore the content is most likely not correct relative to aws provider. I just used some words from that provider to prove the idea.

Given that the `aws_instance.web` resources are created as a collection by use of a `for_each` loop like described below:

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  for_each = {for k,v in var.input_var: k => v if v.enabled}
  name          = each.key
  ami           = each.value.ami
  instance_type = each.value.instance_type
}

resource "aws_db_instance" "db" {
  for_each = var.another_map
  aws_instance_id = aws_instance.web[index(aws_instance.web[*].name, each.value.name)].id
}
```

At creation of the first collection of resources, to each element is assigned a unique read-only `id` by terraform/provider. Given that `var.input_var.key` is always unique, results that also `aws_instance.web.name` will always be unique for each element created.

In the second resources block, I also use a `for_each` loop to cycle through all elements of `var.another_map`. I want to attribute to `aws_instance_id`, the generated `id` from the first resources collection. So I need to first find the element from `aws_instance.web` where the name of it is equal to `each.value.name` while creating `aws_db_instance.db` and than extract the `id` form it.

I tried several ways to achieve this. The closest one is the one exposed above: `aws_instance.web[index(aws_instance.web[*].name, each.value.name)].id`.

So there are two questions that arise from this:

What is the type of `aws_instance.web` (a list of objects, a map of objects, an object which contains a map)?

How would a correct syntax would look like for matching the element and extracting the `id` from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Researching on Matt Schuchard's answer and expanding on it, the output of first resource creation is `object(map(object))` where the keys of the generated map are the same keys of the input variable `var.input_var`.

eg: given the input variable

```
input_var = {
  "website1" = {
    ami = "ami-a1b2c3d4"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    other_var = "some value"
  },
  "webst2" = {
    ami = "ami-a1b2c3d4"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    other_var = "some other value"
  }
}
```

`resource "aws_instance" "web"` block would produce a `aws_instance.web` variable with contents like:

```
aws_instance.web = {
  "website1" = {
    id = 43262    # (read-only) generated by `aws_instance` resource block
    name = "website1"
    ami = "ami-a1b2c3d4"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    # other entries generated by `aws_instance` resource block
  },
  "webst2" = {
    id = 43263   # (read-only) generated by `aws_instance` resource block
    name = "webst2"
    ami = "ami-a1b2c3d4"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    # other entries generated by `aws_instance` resource block
  }
}
```

So when trying to access a specific element from `aws_instance.web` in the second resource block (`aws_db_instance.db`), one can access it by its key, rather than trying to match its `name` attribute.

Therefore, the line `aws_instance_id = aws_instance.web[index(aws_instance.web[*].name, each.value.name)].id` should be replaced with `aws_instance_id = aws_instance.web[each.value.name].id`, if and only if the set of `name`s is a subset of the keys of `aws_instance.web` (I will represent this like `each.value.name[*]` ⊆ `aws_instance.web.keys[*]`)